# Selenium can't find javascript generated elements

Tags: python, selenium

So, what i want do is start the browser, get the page content (with the JavaScript rendered) and find the element i want using BeautifulSoup, here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Edge()
browser.get('https://www.premierleague.com/match/22721')
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
html=bs4(browser.page_source,'html.parser')
print(html.body.main.find('div',attrs={'class':'mcTabs'}))

browser.quit()
```

I get None from the print statement

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are experiencing? Are you getting an exception, or unexpected output? Try to be more specific about what you need help with.

Comment: I simply don't get the element that i want from the print statement, it looks like the JavaScript is not being executed.

Comment: you can directly use this `print(driver.page_source)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have a typo in your code:

```
print(html.body.main.find('div',attrs='class':'mcTabs'}))
```

should be replaced with:

```
print(html.body.main.find('div',attrs={'class':'mcTabs'})) # { is missing
```

The second thing:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
```

is redundant, since you are not using `element` anywhere.

And now to the question itself. I'm not very familiar with `BeautifulSoup`, but what I have found is this:

```
browser.get('https://www.premierleague.com/match/22721')
# wait for element to be present
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.mcTabs"))) 
# get page source when element is already present
html = bs4(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
print(html.body.main.find('div', attrs={'class':'mcTabs'}).prettify())
```

***Explanation:*** you are getting `page_source` of the document which is not full ready yet, that's why you have to wait until `div.mcTabs` will be present in the `DOM` and only then get `page_source`.

***Output:***

```
<div class="mcTabs">
 <section class="mcLatestContainer mcMainTab active" data-ui-args='{"type": "latest"}' data-ui-tab="Latest">
  <nav class="tabs" data-built-class="matchLatestContainer" data-script="pl_tabbed" data-tab-class="mcLatestTab" data-tab-wrap=".tabs" data-widget="tabbed-content">
  </nav>
  <div class="matchLatestContainer">
   <nav class="tabs">
    <ul class="tablist" role="tablist">
     <li class="active" data-tab-index="0" role="tab" tabindex="0">
      Latest
     </li>
     <li data-tab-index="1" role="tab" tabindex="0">
      Photos
     </li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   <div class="blogStreamMatchContainer mcLatestTab active" data-tab-aware-default="true" data-ui-tab="Latest">
    <div class="preMatchContainer" style="display: none;">
     <div class="matchPreviewStreamContainer">
     </div>
     <p class="noContentAvailableContainer" style="display: none;">
      No Content Available
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="liveMatchContainer" style="">
     <section class="matchBlog">
      <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="mcBlogStream">
        <div class="matchReportStreamContainer" data-report-rendered="true">
         <header>
          <h3 class="subHeader">
           Match summary
          </h3>
         </header>
         <div class="wrapper col-12">
          <div class="standardArticle">
           <p>
            Manuel Lanzini scored twice as West Ham United finished the season with a 3-1 win over Everton.
           </p>
           <p>
            The midfielder opened the scoring from the edge of the area on 39 minutes after latching on to Marko Arnautovic's flick of a Cheikhou Kouyate pass.
           </p>
           <p>
            Arnautovic doubled the lead in the 63rd minute with a fierce shot for his 11th goal of the season.
           </p>
...
```

Comment: thank you very much, i'm new to this whole asking questions stuff. Anyways your code helped me a lot, have a good one

Comment: Is this specific to this particular page, or *always* the case? For example, even when the page I'm looking at is fully loaded, I see elements on screen that are not found via selenium. I see them via an inspector, but not in view page source. You seem to be solving a problem of waiting to render, but I thought the question was about html hidden behind a javascript generator script and thus they really aren't in the source. Does that make sense, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Hendy if you can see element in inspector, you can interact with it via Selenium. I guess your element is under `frame` or `iframe` element or even `shadow-root` element. If it is the case, just google it and you will find answer(also in SO)

Comment: Interesting. I was trying to download a bunch of files and could see the ID of all the buttons, but `browser.find_element_by_id('single-download-btn')` found nothing. I ended up copying the inner html from the inspector and working with that directly. I'll refer back to this and try again if I run into the issue.